# ¿Cómo tratar este error de iisnode?

Tags: nodejs, iis, web.config

Estoy tratando de correr una aplicación de node en iis, se supone que ya todo está correcto ero me aparece este error:

```
iisnode was unable to read the configuration file. Make sure the web.config file syntax is correct. In particular, verify the iisnode configuration section matches the expected schema. The schema of the iisnode section that your version of iisnode requires is stored in the %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\iisnode_schema.xml file.
```

---

El código del archivo web.config de mi aplicación es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

  

    <iisnode
      node_env="%node_env%"
      nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
      maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
      maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
      namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"
      maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
      maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
      asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
      initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
      maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
      watchedFiles="*.js;iisnode.yml;iisnode_schema.yml"
      uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"
      gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
      loggingEnabled="false"
      logDirectory="iisnode"
      debuggingEnabled="true"
      debugHeaderEnabled="false"
      debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
      debuggerPathSegment="debug"
      maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
      maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
      maxLogFiles="20"
      devErrorsEnabled="true"
      flushResponse="false"
      enableXFF="false"
      promoteServerVars=""
      configOverrides="iisnode.yml"
      matchType="iisnode_schema.xml"
      schema="iisnode_schema.xml" />   
    
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
      <!-- Redirigir todas las solicitudes a tu archivo index.js -->
      <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^index\.js\/debug[\/]?" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="StaticContent">
        <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="DynamicContent">
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
      <!-- <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ejs" mimeType="text/html" />
            
        </staticContent> -->
    
        <!-- <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.ejs" />
                <add value="index.js" />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument> -->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Es tu web.confg de IIS, haría falta que publiques como tienes configurado tu windows server